# Is there a product.tpl.php for ALL product types in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: theming, commerce

Or do you need product-type1.tpl.php, product-type2.tpl.php, etc? I would like to theme every single product on the site but there are multiple product types.

Comment: Typically you would have a content type per product type for the sake of CMS. You can theme by content type.

Comment: Yeah product types are actually content types. Are you now saying you think product/content-type1.tpl.php is the only way to do it across all products?

Comment: Please see answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following in your theme processing...

```
function YOURTHEME_process_node(&$vars) {

    //dsm($vars);
    //dsm($vars['theme_hook_suggestions']);

    // If some node type then...
    if ($vars['node']->type) {
                // add a template suggestion
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__product';

    }

}
```

Then you add a template file 'node--product.tpl.php'.