# How can I make a template for a product type in Commerce?

Tags: 7, theming, entities, commerce

I want to be able to write my own markup for the fields (see image below) of each product type – how do I do this? My main reason for this is that I want to group them with my own HTML rather than the default provided.

I've tried using `<?php print render($content['field_available_colors']); ?>` and `<?php print render($content['product:field_available_colors']); ?>` in the regular node--[content_type].tpl.php and that didn't work.

I've also tried making a template specific for the product type, but nothing happens. I've been looking at [the latest post in this thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/1245354#comment-11788691), but I can't get any of the suggestion to work either...

I'd very much appreciate some help here, what am I missing?

---

Tried to add the following to template.php, but have no clue what to do with it really. Haven't worked in this way before at all, and this seems pretty steep.

```
function mythemename_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $product_display_types = commerce_product_reference_node_types();
  if (isset($vars['type']) && isset($product_display_types[$vars['node']->type])) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__product__type__' . $vars['node']->type;
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'node-product-type';
    if ($vars['view_mode'] == 'product_list') {
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__product__type__product__list';
      $vars['classes_array'][] = 'node-product-type-product-list';
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is a product reference field, and therefore, the template suggestions are different. That is why creating random node template files is not having any effect. What you want to target is the entity being referenced.

You should check what templates or theme hooks exist in Commerce, and derive the templates from that. You can also add your own suggestions when preprocessing.

Here are some threads that will help:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/1245354
- https://www.drupal.org/node/1245354#comment-11788691
- [Is there a product.tpl.php for ALL product types in Drupal Commerce?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/47665/is-there-a-product-tpl-php-for-all-product-types-in-drupal-commerce)
- https://drupalcommerce.org/discussions/911/customize-way-product-displayed
- https://drupalcommerce.org/discussions/337/how-theme-product-display

Note that if you add to template.php or introduce new templates, you will need to clear your caches so it is picked up by Drupal.

A bulletproof way to find out would be to do `mytheme_preprocess_entity($variables)` in your themes template.php file, and dump out `$variables` when it is preprocessing a product entity. Within it, you will see possible template suggestions *for the product entity itself*.

The same applies for fields as well. `template_preprocess_field`: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7.x

Comment: If I put `mytheme_preprocess_entity($variables)` (with my own theme name of course) in template.php I get `Call to undefined function mythemename_preprocess_entity()`.

Comment: What is calling it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I put it in template as you said.

Comment: Can you post that code?

Comment: The entire template.php basically just is:
`<?php
    mytheme_preprocess_entity($variables)
`
and that's it. My bad, you probably meant for me to add something more, I'm not too familiar working with template though.

Comment: Also found something similar and tried that, see updated question.
But the thing I don't really know what I'm supposed to do with it, now – it's not like everything just magically will work (obviously). Feeling a bit confused at the moment, this seems like a huge part of missing basic functionality in Drupal commerce to be honest.

Comment: It takes way more than that. You're not calling a function, you're defining one. `function mytheme_preprocess_entity(&$variables) { //code here }` where mytheme is your theme name. If you have never used template.php before to do overrides - you should take a step back and look at theme preprocessing first and what that is so you can empower yourself in what is going on here. Then my answer will click.